# Regex: Search and Replace missing tags

Tags: regex, windows, notepad++

I have many tags of this type:

`<a href="foo">`

`<br >`

and I want to make a replace so the output will be:

`<a href="foo" />`

`<br />`

I try this regex, but the "Replace by" part is not very good.

Search: `<([^\s]+)(\s[^>]*?)?(?<!/)>`

Replace by: `\1\2 \>`

Can anyone help me? Actually, I want to change `>` at the end of tag with  `/>` where is missing.

Comment: You want to change link tags to horizontal lines ? Explain what are you trying to do.

Comment: I want to change `>` at the end of tag with  `/>` where is missing.

Comment: Then what's the matter with `hr` replacing `a` ?

Comment: First of all you should know that `>` will be present for **paired tags** and those don't require `/>`

Comment: I think the `a` -> `hr` is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [notepad++ supported](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) positive-look-behind assertion and look-ahead assertion you can math the zero-length between `"` and `>` or `a-space` and `>` with this pattern:

## `(?<=( |"))(?=>)`

this patten does not match anything and in fact it matches the position not a literal string and you can use a string `a-space/` for substitution

## [see demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ll9HQu/1/)